# valueChanges event observable not caught in RXJS in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, valuechangelistener

In constructor I have:

```
this.step1FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  firstLastName: new FormControl('')

});

this.step1FormGroup.get('firstLastName').valueChanges.pipe(
  map((a) => {
    console.log('oy!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
    return a;
  })
);
```

and in template I have this:

```
<form [formGroup]="step1FormGroup">
  <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your name</ng-template>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput
      placeholder='Last name, First name'
      formControlName='firstLastName'>
  </mat-form-field>
  
</form>
```

but I am not catching the valueChanges, so I am not getting the console.log output. How can I fix this, without using the subscribe() method after the pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `valueChanges` function returns an `Observable`, so it's fine if you are `pipe`ing and doing some operations in there, but in order to actually make it work, somewhere, you need to subscribe to that `observable`.

Remember, `observables` by default, are lazy, you don't get the data if you don't subscribe.

```js
this.step1FormGroup.get('firstLastName').valueChanges.pipe(
  map((a) => {
    console.log('oy!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
    return a;
  })
).subscribe(); // here
```

Also, I recommend moving that logic from your constructor to `ngOnInit`, that's where all the data initialization should be handled.